# Delete system field from Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a way to delete system fields in Visual Studio Team Services?

We need to delete a field called `Reason` (`System.Reason`) from `Test case` work item type.

The purpose for this is, we have added custom values for the `State` and have created our own custom `Reason` field. So, we need to remove the existing `Reason` field.

It would be great if we get to know how to delete this or any workaround (say, disable/hide or edit this field to add more values to it).

Answer (score 1):

No. System fields are exactly that: **system** fields. They are intentionally not open to removal/modification. This way, certain core fields can be guaranteed by the software to exist and be totally consistent regardless of any other modifications made to the user-defined portions of the work item form.